# Strange pronunciation of "door"

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, australian-english

I have just heard Australian-English actor Rob Inglis repeatedly pronounce the word "door" so that it rhymes with "poor".

In what dialect is that pronunciation found? Is it Australian?

**Edit - clarification**

My "Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary" gives the pronunciation [dɔ:(r)] for "door" and [pʊǝ(r)] for "poor"

Mr Inglis' pronunciation is [dʊǝ], not [dɔ:].

Comment: Does he say "Hodor"? ;)

Comment: What dialect doesn't?  I'm American and that's how we say it in AE.  I'm pretty sure BE they are pretty close if not exactly the same.

Comment: Uh, "door" does rhyme with "poor", at least to a pretty good approximation.

Comment: according to Collins there are two received pronunciation one like Door that rhyme with Pour and the other http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/poor   good question

Comment: Perhaps the question is whether "poor" rhymes with "four" and "for" and is a homophone of "pour".  "Door" also rhymes with the pronunciation I am used to for all of those.  But I occasionally hear "poor" pronounced differently, rhyming with "sure".  It would be very odd to hear "door" pronounced that way.

Comment: How do you pronounce *poor*? Does it rhyme with *shore, fir, sewer, sure*, or  none of the above?

Comment: In Standard BE *door* and *poor* are not the same. They may be the same in some regional accents (North-East comes to mind). In Std BE, *door* rhymes with *pour* and *poor* rhymes with *dour*. Go figure (as we Brits don't say).

Comment: I have clarified Mr Inglis' pronunciation by editing the original post. (I hope the IPA characters come across correctly.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach, _poor_ rhymes with _dour_? Are you quite sure about that?

Comment: @BrianHooper  I'm suspecting he meant *doer* instead of *dour*.

Comment: @Brian Hooper: Yes; he means poor rhymes with dour rhymes with tour.

Comment: Related question on Linguistics SE (I hope my answer there might help provide some background info about the etymology of "door"): [“oo” in “poor”, “door” and “doom”](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14517)

Comment: @sumelic, wow.  I have never heard *dour* pronounced to rhyme with *tour*, only with *hour*.  Yet I see it's the first listed pronunciation on m-w.com. Learning all sorts of things here.  :-)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Not sure about that - ODO lists pronounciations as /dɔː/ and /pɔː/, with /pʊə/ as an option ([poor](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/poor);[door](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/door)). I would say that having a different pronounciation is less common than the same one - the Potteries, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mid-Ulster English, admittedly far from Australia,

> /ʉ/ is possible before /r/ in floor, whore, door, board, etc.
>    — [Wikipedia Ulster English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulster_English#Vowels)

For pronunciation of /ʉ/ see [Wikipedia  Close central rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_central_rounded_vowel)
which has a link to an [audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Close_central_rounded_vowel.ogg) file.